# Getting working Scala Android Project under SBT

Tags: android, scala, intellij-idea, sbt, proguard

**Note** A lot of the information available is scattered, incomplete, or about 2 years old.

Ideally I want a Gradle-driven Android and Scala project that uses gradles structure, and code it in IntelliJ IDEA. However I have realised that is a fantasy.

So it comes SBT, which I was so hoping to avoid, not because it's bad, but just because I am learning Gradle and prefer to stick with it.

So eventually I cloned a [Scaloid SBT project](https://github.com/pocorall/hello-scaloid-sbt). And that managed to get all the ducks in a row:

1. Updated and cleaned up local java SDKs, now running fully on java7_x64, with paths
2. Sorted Scala and SBT, both work.
3. followed the [Scaloid instructions](https://github.com/pocorall/hello-scaloid-sbt)
4. in steps the confusion - the [android-sdk-plugin](https://github.com/pfn/android-sdk-plugin#usage) is quite poorly documented.

   - and because all of the other 30 sources I used I figured out using proguard is pretty essential because of the size of the scala libraries, thankfully the android-sdk-plugin handles a lot of that for me, and so does `build.sbt` in the Scaloid SBT project.
   - **BUT** I get

     `[error] (android:proguard) java.io.FileNotFoundException: Programming\Android_x64\sdk\platforms\android-19\android.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)`
   - Which is basically either the plugin, sbt, my stupidity, the wrath of the gods, but it is breaking because of the space in the path `D:\Apps - Programming\Android_x64` and for the life of me I have no idea where to set the path manually so that I can wrap the damn thing in quotes.

Help is much appreciated.
If anyone has successfully managed to get a Scala Android project and its driven by Gradle I would greatly appreciate detailed instructions or a project to clone.